# Need to highlight the flag in an email using workflow

Tags: sharepoint-online

Depending on the Status I have to highlight the flag in an email using SharePoint designer through workflow. Any solution is there for this task?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to set the High Importance flag in an email with SharePoint Designer.

If you are able to develop Visual Studio solutions, one solution could be for you to develop a custom web service that sends the email. In this web service you could set the High Importance flag before sending the email. Once this web service is developed and deployed, you could call it from your SharePoint Designer workflow using the "Call HTTP Web Service" activity.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Designer does not provide the highlighting natively in the text attribute toolbar.

The trick is to copy/paste a highlighted phrase from MS Word into the E-mail Message Definition window, then you can apply it to text or fields/strings however you'd like.

Provided that the recipients' e-mail client supports HTML, the highlighting should come through.

Hope this helps someone.